# The fastest way to get the sum of character orders?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find the fastest way to get the sum of a character orders in a string

for example if the string contains:

```
ABAACA;
```

Then the sum of character A will be:

```
(A=0)+(A=2)+(A=3)+(A=5)=10;

 A=10;
```

i know  some way to that but it takes too long,so would you please tell me how can i get the fastest sum?

Comment: The _fastest_ way is to have already run the program before you start the timer. (or just a simple hard-coded `cout << 'A=' << 10 << ';\n';`) Why don't you show the code you've got so people can address your issue on your terms.

Comment: This is weird as the "sum" is the same regardless of whether the character is in the first position or not

Comment: Do you need a sum of order for one specific character or for every character present in a string? That is a single sum for A only or three sums for A, B and C?

Comment: No a specific character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fastest non parallel solution:

-go over every char.

-increase count if match (`if(ch=='A')count+=i;`).

there is just no faster way, because you MUST visit each character.

Anyway if you have a working solution, it's probably the fastest already..

Comment: Personally I don't agree with the "fastest non parallel" assertion you've made here regarding standard loop. I know compilers nowadays can highly optimize your code (and e.g. unroll the loop if it is beneficial), but from theoretical point of view I consider loop unwinding to be faster than its classic equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way I see to do this with C++ (since there's nothing else describing your problem), involves parallel processing:

1. Parallel scan and in-place indexing
2. [Reduction](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf)

Although it might not be what you were looking for.

Comment: +1 for the link to the parallel reduction. With the help of GPU, it should be indeed the fastest way to solve this problem ... as long as the data transfer is not too long.

Comment: Also to notice that **"it must be worth it"**. If you have a string of 9 characters you'd definitely better off doing that on the host.

Comment: for 98% this is a string of length that eliminates the need of GPU

Answer (score 0):

If no parallel tools are in place the fastest solution would be to just visit each char in loop and increase sum.

Comment: Please don't encourage people to post "gib me teh codez" by providing it for them. It does this site a huge disservice.

Comment: @mah changed, I've removed the code, please remove downvote

Comment: Removed mine; mine was not the first though.

Comment: @other downvoter can you please remove your downvote too?

Comment: @other downvoter care to remove your vote please?

Answer (score 0):

```
int count_match ( char* str, int length, char digit )
{
  int output = 0;
  for ( int index = 0; index < length; ++ index )
    output += index & - (str[index] == digit);
  return output;
}
```

If the length of the string could be known at compile time, then you could conceivably template that value out and let the compiler vectorize the loop for you.